# Why won't my view get updated in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, ng-hide

I'm trying to do some error handling for my web app ;  more specifically, I want to display an error message whenever the server fails to deliver a message to the client.

I have a controller that is called by another controller(using a callback function after getting the http response) on an event(Error) and the aforementioned controller is supposed to set the ng-hide attribute of div containing error messages to false but it seems like the view isn't getting updated with the new value. So, the div and the message are never displayed. I've tried everything but I can't seem to figure out what is the problem. Thank you!

Here is my code for the error handling controller

```
var errorCtrl=function($scope,$timeout){
$scope.errorDivHide = true;
$scope.$on("Error", function(event, error){
var statustxt = error.statusText;

notifiyClientOfError = function(){
$timeout(function(){

$scope.errorDivHide = false;
console(String(errorDivHide));// prints false, as it should but the div wont appear

$scope.message = "Error :"+String(statustxt);
});
}
notifyClientOfError();
```

Here is my html

```
<div ng-controller ="errorCtrl">
  <div id ="errorDiv" ng-hide = "errorDivHide"/>
     {{message}}
   </div>
   <p> {{errorDivHide}} </p> ( I wanted to see the value; it happened to be true   even after I updated it in the controller)
</div>
```

Comment: you need to chenge your ng-hide to ng-show and you have an error in your <div>. It's gonna be `<div ng-controller ="errorCtrl">` instead of `<div> ng-controller ="errorCtrl">`

Comment: the "<div> ng-controller" was a typo; I didn't copy and paste my code; I retyped it. My actual html does have "<div ng-controller ="errorCtrl">". Why should I use ng-show instead?

Comment: because if your variable 'errorDivHide' is true, this directive(ng-hide) would hide your div

Comment: I know but in my controller, in my event handler($scope.on("Error")", I set erroDivHide to false, so that it would appear. Is that the wrong idea? I want the div to be hidden until my event handler($scope.$on("Error")" is called.